# ¿Se puede hacer un format de timestamp?

Tags: php

```
 // $timestamp    = "";
  $datetimeFormat = 'YmdHis';
  $date = new DateTime('now');
 // $date->setTimestamp($timestamp);      
  echo $date->format($datetimeFormat);
```

El resultado de ese código es: 20180411131121

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
<?php
 // $timestamp    = "";
  $datetimeFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
  $date = new DateTime('now');
 // $date->setTimestamp($timestamp);      
  echo $date->format($datetimeFormat);

?>
```

Este es el resultado:

> 2018-04-11 11:28:53

[Aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php) tienes una explicación completa de cómo dar formato a un `timestamp`

Comment: Gracias por dedicar tu tiempo. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitás es el `timestamp` podés usar el método `getTimestamp()` del objeto `DateTime`.

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
var_dump($date->getTimestamp());
```

Salida:

```
int(1523454056)
```

Pero si lo que necesitas es darle formato, estabas en lo correcto, sólo que te faltaba ponerle lo necesario para que sea visualmente correcto.

```
$datetimeFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date = new DateTime('now');
var_dump($date->format($datetimeFormat));
```

Salida:

```
string(19) "2018-04-11 13:44:02"
```

[Acá](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) tenés los formatos aceptados por `DateTime()`.

Y [esto es el código](https://ideone.com/81Myk9) en ejecución para que puedas ver los diferentes resultados.

Comment: Gracias por dedicar tu tiempo. Un saludo